# Python connect to MySQL server using SSHTunnelForwarder and MySQLdb

Tags: python, ssh

I'm tring to understand what I should do in order to connect to a remote MySQL server using SSH.

```
    from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('192.168.0.60', 22),
        ssh_password="MySSHPASSWORD",
ssh_username="MUSSHUserName",
remote_bind_address=('192.168.0.30', 3306)) as server:

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='UserNameOnSQLSERVER', passwd='PasswordOnSQLSERVER', host='192.168.0.60', db='myDB',
                           port=server.local_bind_port)
```

I've been able to connect to this server with the above configuration throw MySQL Workbench and Run queries and everything worked great

The problem is that when I'm trying to connect this DB by the above code I keep getting error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.60' (10060)")
```

I also tried to change the ip in MySQLdb.connect to be

```
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='kiboUser', passwd='Lb24@db30#kL68', host='192.168.0.60', db='dbKiboDashboard',
                           port=server.local_bind_port)
```

and I got the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.30' (10060)")
```

Can please someone help me understand what im doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: Please, clarify details of your set up: 1. Your local address is 192.168.0.60 and remote server with MySQL is on 192.168.0.30 ? 2. Or you have ssh proxy on 192.168.0.60 ? 3. Have your tried create ssh tonel using command like ssh -L 3307:mysql-host-name.com:3306 ssh_user@ssh_host -A and then to connect to MySQL via localhost on port 3307 ?

Comment: 1) The MySQL server is 192.168.0.30 and I can reach it through 192.168.0.60

Comment: What is your server.local_bind_port value?

Comment: The server.local_bind_port value is 50157

Comment: Then you should try to connect to MySQL via this TCP port

Answer (score 3):

remote_bind_address is the one you are tunneling into. Make sure to verify the server's TCP port that is listening. 
To verify this, you could try the command

> netstat

or

> netstat -tln

This should work:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ServerIP', sshport), #The server's IP and SSH port
    ssh_password="MySSHPASSWORD",
    ssh_username="MUSSHUserName",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)) as server: #The server's TCP IP and port, you're tunneling

conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='UserNameOnSQLSERVER', passwd='PasswordOnSQLSERVER', host='127.0.0.1',
                       port=server.local_bind_port) #Your TCP IP and port (your end of the tunnel)
```